# What does pregnancy dreams mean?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality, dreams, philosophy-of-mind, parenting

I had  a weird  dream  about  my  boobs  being  as  hard  as  a morning  stiffy

oh  and  for  some  reason  thinking  of  my fiancee  in the  same  dream  made  me  pregnant  and  I was  still  stuck  in my  house with  the man I  live  with

not just  the nipples  :p  both  breasts. oh and  I just  stood  on my head  for a microsecond

I has  a  son already